# How to center a dataframe in streamlit new version

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I had no problem with the alignment in the old version but when I upgraded to the  new version I saw this happen. I tried the following 3 different approach below the dataframe but none of them fixes the problem. Is there any way to work around it?
[image]

```py
#Sets df size with width 1000 and height 300, but width has a limited range
st.dataframe(df, 1000, 300) 

st.dataframe(df, use_container_width=True) 

st.write(df, use_container_width=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask this question for a while now but yet didn't get any response until I figured a way to handle my problem.

I used Streamlit AgGrid component to fix my problem. `AgGrid()` by default will center the dataframe, it also has other awesome features of handling data frames much better than `st.dataframe()` and it is pretty simple and clean. I could even choose to color the data frame to my liking which I found pretty cool and interactive.

In case you face similar problem and want to take this approach I will recommend you visit [Streamlit AgGrid component](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components) to know the inside of the component and how it is implemented.

```py
from st_aggrid import AgGrid

AgGrid(df)
```

OUTPUT:

[image]